# Is it possible to use ScheduledExecutorService with Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

Is it possible to use ScheduledExecutorService with a webdyno or heroku shutdown the java process if no web call are made.

That an example of what I want to use

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
  Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

final ScheduledFuture<?> timeHandle =
  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimePrinter(System.out), 0, 10, SECONDS);    

scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {

  }
}, 60*60, SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use the `ScheduledExecutorService` on Heroku.  There are no Java API limitations when running on Heroku.  However, if you try to just shutdown the process, Heroku will attempt to start it back up.  To handle scaling on Heroku you will need to call the Heroku management APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that, if you only run a single dyno web app, the web process will be stopped if they are not receiving any traffic.

A scheduler thread that runs inside a web process should only do work related to the process itself, e.g clear out internal caches, etc. If you stick to this use case, you don't need the scheduler process if your whole web process has been idled out.

If your scheduler does work outside of the web process, then we recommend that you factor it into a dedicated [worker or "clock" process](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku) and scale it to exactly one dyno (effectively a singleton process). Heroku will make sure the process is running, restarting it if it crashes, etc.

The worker/clock process should do an infinite loop with a sleep call so it wakes up every X seconds and performs work. You will be charged a full dyno hour per hour you're running a worker process like this which is of course not always economical.

If you only want to schedule something every 10 minutes or less frequently, you can use the [Heroku scheduler service](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) which will only incur costs for the actual time it runs, not for the sleep time.